# Magento 2 Add product to cart programmatically returning to original price

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart

I have a product of  $1, because I change the price later.

What I'm doing is that I send the price on an Ajax request to a Controller, just like this:

```
                  $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://baseurl/application/cart/application',
                        data: {product_id: '1',grand_total:120},
                        method: "POST"
                    }).done(function(response){
                        console.log('DONE');
                        console.log(response);
                        var sections = ['cart'];
                        customerData.invalidate(sections);
                        customerData.reload(sections, true);
                         window.location.href = "http://baseurl/checkout";
                    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                        console.log('FAILED');
                        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                    });
```

Then in the controller I add the product to cart like this:

```
 public function execute(){
        //I'm using \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
        $request = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $product_id = $request['product_id'];
        $price = $request['grand_total'];
        $params = array(
            'formKey' => $this->formKey,
            'product_id' => $product_id,
            'qty' => 1
        );

        $productFactory = $this->product->create();
        try{
            $product = $productFactory->load($product_id);
            $product->setPrice($price);
            $this->cart->addProduct($product,$params);
            $this->cart->save();
        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            return $request;
        }
    }
```

When I'm redirected to checkout by the promise, the new price is shown just for a second, then switch back to the original product's price ($1)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quote item custom price. Eg:

```
$item->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
$product->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Above code, you can use under **checkout_cart_product_add_after** event or you can loop inside your controller.

Comment: Hi, what is $item class? is it the same Model/Cart? and also for $product

Comment: $item is the quote item and $product is $product = $item->getProduct();

Comment: so this means that I need to get the item of the cart, then add custom price, and add setIsSuperMode to the actual product loaded by id?

Comment: No, that's way will be slow. Use checkout_cart_product_add_after instead. Here is the way inside event listener class: $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $product = $item->getProduct();